# Reuse code in iPhone, Android and a Web applications

Tags: iphone, android, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm about to develop an app for iPhone, Android, and for web too. I think there must be some "standard" way for doing this, in order to reuse as much code as possible.

Which is the best way for doing that? Webservices? (only if the app uses internet) Maybe an API? Another way?

Just for the record, the web application will probably be developed in Ruby On Rails 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few cross platform development tools out there that let you write once and compile for multiple platforms.  I know I've seen questions on both tool here on SO, so others might have some good advice on these specific products.

PhoneGap
http://www.phonegap.com/

Appcelerator
http://www.appcelerator.com/

Barring that, if you are looking at doing native development on each platform, the web services APIs are a good way to go.  I've built an App that is heavily data driven, and I built out RESTful services over JSON that do the heavy lifting for the iPhone, Android and Web versions.

There still is quite a bit of work that goes into implementing a feature on each platform, but once I architect code on one platform the hard, creative work is done and it's just porting it to the next platform (Same applies, mostly, to the graphics as well).  Since I am coding for each platform individually I do try to take advantage of both code and UI conventions for that platform to give the user a native experience (say building menus for the menu button on Android, something not supported on iPhone).  To me that's a benefit of developing for each platform individually, however, it also greatly increases time to market for each version.

Since you're looking at Objective-C, Java and Ruby, 3 completely different languages, there's not an easy way to develop a shared library without using a intermediary layer like those linked above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all three are different languages, so anything you write for one won't work for the other. An API on a server may be able to get you the same data to all, but its highly unlikely that you'll get any reusable code. I'm doing the same thing, and realize that, so I am just sharing common things such as UI and code-design between them.